# DevExpress: row index in datatable -> row handle in gridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

I can’t understand how to get the Row Handle in the GridView by the index in the DataTable DataSource ...
 (VS2019 C # DX19.2.5 WinForms)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an index of the record in the data source `rowIndex` then you can get its row handle by using method [`GetRowHandle(int)`](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.GetRowHandle(System.Int32)):

```
int rowHandle = gridView.GetRowHandle(rowIndex);
```

If you have a `DataRow record` from binded `DataTable` and you want to get row handle by the `record` then you can use method [`FindRow(object)`](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.FindRow(System.Object)):

```
int rowHandle = gridView.FindRow(record);
```

Comment: @Altom Updated answer. Added information how to find row handle by data row.